# How to write correct regex so JSLint will validate?

Tags: javascript, regex, jslint

I use a very simple regex in a replace function that causes JSLint.com to report errors:

```
srcTemplate.replace(/{x}/g, tileX);
```

A quick search around the internet gave a lot of suggestions, but none of them answered my question:

How can I enhance the regex so JSLint will validate AND the function will keep working?

Comment: And what error does jslint report?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The regex `/{x}/` is invalid because curly braces have special meaning in regular expressions. Some regex engines may still treat it as a valid regex by assuming that you probably meant literal curly braces instead of quantifiers, but perhaps JSLint is more strict here. So if you're planning to match a literal `{x}`, you need the regex

```
/\{x\}/
```

to be on the safe side (although it's unclear why you'd need a regex for that at all since it's a simple text replacement).

Usually, you use curly braces as a quantifier. For example `x{3}` matches `xxx`; `x{3,5}` matches `xxx`, `xxxx` and `xxxxx`, and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much Pietzcker! I will evaluate your solution and also try a simple replacement function to see what works best for me, but for now, you helped me a lot.